# Saving login details in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am new to programming.

I am creating a project in which i want to store login details into database but i am using Combobox list because there are various types of user and for that particular selected user i want to get the info store in my database.

My form looks like this...

- User Id : Textbox
- Password : Textbox
- User Type : ComboBoxlist

In that comboboxlist there are 3 types of users.

So, how do I store the above mentioned details of login into my database?

I hope I have framed the question in the right way...:)

Thank you

Comment: There are many ways to do that ,DB,File,Application,ect...

Comment: Basically you will have at least 2 tables in your database to hold that information. One is the user type table that you use to populate the dropdown (and later in the code I'm guessing you will use for role based authentication), and one for the users with a foreign key to user type table. Please note that asp.net already have it's own [built it authentication model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x).

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try a Database Design With 3 Tables.

1. User Table - Store User Login Information
2. Roles Table - Store Available Roles in the System
3. User Roles - Store Roles assigned to each user

something like this

User Table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users
(
    UserId INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Users_UserI PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    UserNm VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Uq_Users_UserNm UNIQUE,
    FirstNm VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastNm VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(255),
    Pwd NVARCHAR(1000)
)
```

Roles Table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Roles
(
    RoleId INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Roles_RoleId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    RoleCd VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Uq_Roles_RoleCd UNIQUE,
    RoleNm VARCHAR(255)
)
```

User Roles

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserRoles 
(
    UserRoleId INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_UserRoles_UserRoleId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    UserId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Fk_UserRoles_UserId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Users(UserId),
    RoleId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Fk_UserRoles_RoleId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Roles(Roleid)
)
```